# Typo3 & realurl: Page not found in IE - other browsers work fine

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, url-rewriting, typo3, realurl

I have encountered a very strange behavior of the IE and don't know how to solve it:

I´m working on a typo3-site (http://alkitronic.com). The site is multi-language and has realurl installed.
The problem is: When i open a subpage in the IE and try to change the language - realurl generates the wrong url and shows a "Page Not Found"-Page... but this only happens in IE, other browsers work fine.

Example:
Start-Page: http://www.alkitronic.com/drehmomentschrauber-hersteller/
Language change to english:
IE-url: http://www.alkitronic.com/drehmomentschrauber-hersteller/en/unternehmen/

Chrome-url: http://www.alkitronic.com/en/unternehmen/

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Jacksbox, I'm pulling your answer out of the question and posting it here for future reference.

The language-switcher was configured incorrectly. The urls were `en/unternehmen` but they should be `/en/unternehmen` (notice the leading `/`